# How to extract different types of sub-strings from a string in python using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

As the title, I'm supposed to get some sub-strings from a string which looks like this: "-23/45 + 14/9". What I need to get from that string is the four numbers and the operator in the middle. What has confused me is that how to use only one regular expression pattern to do this. Below is the requirement:

Write a regular expression patt that can be used to extract
(numerator,denominator,operator,numerator,denominator)
from a string containing a fraction, an arithmetic operator, and a fraction. You may
assume there is a space before and after the arithmetic operator and no spaces
surrounding the / character in a fraction. And all fractions will have a numerator and
denominator.
Example:

```
>>> s = "-23/45 + 14/9"
>>> re.findall(patt,s)
[( "-23","45","+","14","49")]
>>> s = "-23/45 * 14/9"
>>> re.findall(patt,s)
[( "-23","45","*","14","49")]
```

In general, your code should handle any of the operators +, -, * and /.
Note: the operator module for the two argument function equivalents of the arithmetic
(and other) operators

My problem here is that how to use only one regular expression to do this. I have thought about getting the sub strings contain numbers and stop at any character which is not a number, but this will miss the operator in the middle. Another idea is to include all the operators( + - * /) and stop at white space, but this will make first and last two numbers become together. Can anybody give me a direction how to solve this problem with only one regular expression pattern? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regular expressions support an "or"-operator, so `A|B` matches `A` or `B`

Comment: The problem is that I only need the operator in the middle but do not need the divide sign /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(-?\d+)\s*\/\s*(\d+) *([+*\/-])\s*(-?\d+)\s*\/(\d+)
```

**[Click for regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FaS6Tl/4)**

You can extract the required information from Group 1 to Group 5

**Explanation:**

- `(-?\d+)` - matches an optional `-` followed by 1+ occurrences of a digit and capture it in Group 1
- `\s*\/\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace followed by a `/` followed by 0+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `(\d+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit and capture it in Group 2
- `*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a space
- `([+*\/-])` - matches one of the operators in `+`,`-`,`/`,`*` and captures it in Group 3
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `(-?\d+)` - matches an optional `-` followed by 1+ occurrences of a digit and capture it in Group 4
- `\s*\/` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace followed by `/`
- `(\d+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit and capture it in Group 5

Comment: Thanks soooo much, this problem has confused me for a whole afternoon and now I learned something new......

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider selecting it as the answer if it solved your issue :)